# Why are Question Marks (?)'s appearing in my posts?

Tags: wordpress

So on a clients WordPress site, they noticed some question marks appearing in some of their old posts.

Here is an example: http://theblazingcenter.com/2014/07/8-ways-to-beat-temptation.html

Now, when I go into the post to edit it, there they are, just simple question marks sitting there. I can delete them and they go away, but how did they get there? How can I get them out of older posts easily?

It isn't even as if they are all replacing certain characters either...some of them are simply added in there, while others do replace apostrophes.

Comment: `UPDATE db.table SET post=REPLACE(post, '?', '');` There is no way to know if there 'should' be an apostrophe or not in the value...

Comment: Thanks for the response...can you give me a bit more of a step by step on this? I'm not sure what to do with what you gave me.

Comment: There is no way programmatically to know if a question mark should be completely removed, or is replacing a space, a period, or an apostrophe. (I have seen them all in your example). The only think you can do is replace all of them with nothing, or manually edit all of your posts to remove the question marks. As far as where they are coming from, there is no true way to know. MySQL doesn't use `?`. PDO uses them for prepared statements. PHP doesn't use them typically...so frankly I'm not sure how they got there... There is truly no step-by-step for this problem...